# Tikzpicture (horizontal) aligning caption with respect to node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a tikzpicture with 2 nodes. One node is image and other node is axis label. I want to center the caption with respect to image node, rather than on the complete tikzpicture. Please help and below is my latex,

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics {}}
      \node (ylabel) at (-3.25,0) {$\frac{test}{test}$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionsetup{type=figure,font=footnotesize}
    \captionof{figure}{This is some junk text as caption for figure 1}
  \end{minipage}

  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics {}}
      \node (ylabel) at (-3.25,0) {$\frac{test}{test}$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionsetup{type=figure,font=footnotesize}
    \captionof{figure}{This is some junk text as caption for figure 2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do I understand your problem correctly that you want to have the text `Figure 3.8: This is some junk text as caption for figure 1` centered vertically and horizontally within the left image? Is the `Figure 3.8:` part also necessary?

Comment: Yes you are right. `Figure 3.8: This is some junk text as caption for figure 1` should be horizontally centered to the left image. I wanted the caption of Figure 3.8 and 3.9 to be vertically aligned, that's why I use minipage and it works. Hence, there is no issue with vertical alignment. For your second question, Figure 3.8 is necessary for me

Comment: Moreover, I tried `trim left` but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `image` node, add `\useasboundingbox (image.south east) rectangle (image.north west);`. Anything added after that will not be considered with respect to the bounding box of the `tikzpicture`.

To make room for the node with the fraction, I reduced the width of the `minipage`s a bit, and added `\hfill` between them. Note also that as you are inside a `figure` environment, you do not need to use `\captionof`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz,caption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{type=figure,font=footnotesize}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [inner sep=0pt] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{}};
      \useasboundingbox (image.south east) rectangle (image.north west);
      \node (ylabel) at (-3.25,0) {$\frac{test}{test}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{This is some junk text as caption for figure 1}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [inner sep=0pt] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{}};
      \useasboundingbox (image.south east) rectangle (image.north west);
      \node (ylabel) at (-3.25,0) {$\frac{test}{test}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{This is some junk text as caption for figure 2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot for the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Please have a look at Torbjørn's solution, I believe it is easier and cleaner than mine.

---

If you want to center the caption to the complete minipage/tikzpicture: Thats easy. Just add `justification=centering` to your `\captionformat`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}};
            \node (ylabel) at (-3.25,0) {$\frac{test}{test}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionsetup{type=figure,font=footnotesize,justification=centering,format=plain}
        \captionof{figure}{This is some junk text as caption for figure 1}

        % Just for demo, you can remove these two lines
        \noindent\rule{1pt}{6pt}
        \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}};
            \node (ylabel) at (-3.25,0) {$\frac{test}{test}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionsetup{type=figure,font=footnotesize,justification=centering,format=plain}
        \captionof{figure}{This is some junk text as caption for figure 2}

        % Just for demo, you can remove these two lines
        \noindent\rule{1pt}{6pt}
        \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The additional lines show that the captions are centered within the minipage.

---

If you want to center the caption to the "real" image - the grey boxes in my example - then you have to tell the caption where your image starts and ends. This can be accomplished with the `margin={<left>,<right>}` parameter for \captionsetup. I've done this here for my gray boxes with `margin={1cm,0.4cm}`, but it might be necessary to adjust those values for your image.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}};
            \node (ylabel) at (-3.25,0) {$\frac{test}{test}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionsetup{type=figure,font=footnotesize,justification=centering,margin={1cm,0.4cm},format=plain}
        \captionof{figure}{This is some junk text as caption for figure 1}
        \noindent\rule{1pt}{6pt}
        \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}};
            \node (ylabel) at (-3.25,0) {$\frac{test}{test}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionsetup{type=figure,font=footnotesize,justification=centering,margin={1cm,0.4cm},format=plain}
        \captionof{figure}{This is some junk text as caption for figure 2}
        \noindent\rule{1pt}{6pt}
        \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the caption is now centered relative to the `\included` image.